# Avoid changing values in console

Tags: php, console

How can I avoid that users changing the values in the console. As example my link is:
`example.com/delete.php?id=8`. When I'm open my console and I change the 8 to 10 then row 10 is deleted.

How can I avoid this? Or by which way I can do it instead of the URL?

Comment: I do not think you can "change" the browser behaviour.

Comment: But how can I avoid this?

Comment: If the users have the right "privilege" they can (i think) modify id8 and id10, so there is no difference. You can "stop" a user that doesn't have some autority.

Comment: What do you mean with: You can stop a user? Could you tell me how? When I have the link that says example.com/delete.php?id=8, I cannot check the 8 anymore because users change the 8 to 10 in the console (F12) because it's a generated HTML link.

Comment: You cannot do that, after all you need to "pass" the var with a get or post system and then the user with the console can change it. You cannot solve this. (As far as i know)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<form method=post action=delete.php ><button type=submit value=8 name=id>delete</button></form>` and then, in the PHP, use `$_POST['id']` instead of `$_GET['id']`.

You can also use `$_SESSION`s to see if the user is logged in and if he is allowed to delete that id; For instance, when delivering the page set something as `$_SESSION['allow_id'] = 8` and then, on the PHP side, you could do something as:

`if ((!empty($_SESSION['allow_id'])) && (!empty($_POST)) && ($_SESSION['allow_id'] == $_POST['id'])) { // allow the deletion } else { // don't allow }`

Comment: And if you use the same tags in a batch on the client side with whatever you want as values ? It doesn't solve a security problem.

Comment: edited the answer to account for the security problem

Answer (score 0):

The security of an application must never be only on the client side.

You must always consider that URIs called on the client side can be called not just via a form.

If your interface offers a short list of choices, the webservice or server script must check the same reduced choice list before before any other treatment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the best way to do this? Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: It depends on the context, and when you designing your application. For exemple, if the user can delete only specific items in your database, you have to check in your database if the user is allowed to deleted the item given in your URI before deleting.

Comment: Just with a control query you mean? And the code: if($row['userid'] == $_SESSION['userid']){//delete}else{//you're not allowed}? Is this the good way?

Comment: @DrupalStarter gathered that your database row has a userid field and it matches the session id then I'd say that that's enough

Comment: Is this the simplest way to do?

Comment: The simplest way would be using a non-database method, such as the example I've shown you in my answer.